# How can I manage multiple AdWords accounts using the same login?

Tags: google, google-adsense, google-ads

This is the situation. I have an AdWords account which I use with my own email address. My girlfriend has another which she uses with her email address. However I am managing her ads for her so I want to be able to log into her AdWords and manage her account using my email address.

Annoyingly though when I gave myself admin access I was told I would need to use a new email address.

Buutt... I used to work with an agency that managed my AdWords; and all I did was give them access and as far as I know they were just able to log in using their own email address.

Has something changed with security recently for AdWords to allow (agents) to manage multiple clients AdWords from a single email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Google "[My Client Center](http://www.google.com/adwords/myclientcenter/)" account.

> Your job is complex enough. Let us help you simplify it. With My Client Center (MCC), our powerful tool for large advertisers and third parties, you can manage multiple AdWords accounts quickly and easily from a single location.

Once you have that setup, you can set other accounts to allow you to manage them.

Comment: thanks mate this is useful to know. Do you know how much it costs?

Comment: Doesn't cost anything as far as I know. I think they generally intend for it to be used by ad agencies and the like, but I'm just a lonely web developer and they gave me an account.

Comment: lol okay thanks for your help doesn't look like many people knew about this. Cheers :-)